# Android: Salvando dados em arquivos

Tags: java, android

Estou com problemas para utilizar arquivos no android.

Salvo o arquivo e utilizo tranquilamente até fechar o aplicativo, quando abro o app novamente o arquivo é recriado e perco os dados gravados.

Testei varias soluções, estou com esse codigo agora:

```
public class PersistenciaSerial {
    String arquivo;
    Context cont;
    File fileDir;

    public PersistenciaSerial(Context context, String fileName) {
        cont = context;
        fileDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/saude");
        if(fileDir.isDirectory()){
            fileDir.mkdirs();
        } else {
            Log.e("Diretório já existente", fileDir.getName());
        }
        arquivo = fileDir+"/"+fileName;
    }

    public Object pegarObjeto() {
        Object lista = null;
        //Classe responsavel por recuperar os objetos do arquivo
        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = cont.openFileInput(arquivo);
            Log.e("Teste de fileinputstream", fileInputStream.toString());
            ObjectInputStream objLeitura = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
            lista = (Object)objLeitura.readObject();
            objLeitura.close();
            objLeitura.close();
            Log.e("Teste OFF Pegando", String.valueOf(lista));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Teste Pegando False", e.toString());
        }
        return lista;
    }

    public void persistir(Object listaEntrada) {
        //Classe responsavel por inserir os objetos
        try {
            Log.e("Teste OFF Persistindo", "Persistindo");
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = cont.openFileOutput(arquivo, 1);
            Log.e("Teste de fileoutputstream", fileOutputStream.toString());
            ObjectOutputStream objGravar = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            //Grava o objeto cliente no arquivo
            objGravar.writeObject(listaEntrada);
            objGravar.flush();
            Log.e("Teste OFF Persistindo", arquivo);
            Log.e("Teste OFF Persistindo", String.valueOf(listaEntrada));
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Teste Persistindo False", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Coloquei a classe toda por desespero mesmo.

Já agradeço pelo seu tempo dedicado a minha duvida.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize um `BufferedWriter` com um `FileWriter` onde o segundo parâmetro seja  `true` para fazer append no mesmo ([FileWriter](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html)):

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(arquivo, true));
writer.write("texto");
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

Observe que o `BufferedWriter` também tem método de `append` o que pode ser mais claro em alguns casos.

Answer (score 1):

Para que seja possível acrescentar dados a um arquivo aberto com `openFileOutput(String name, int mode)` o valor para o parâmetro *mode* deve ser [Context.MODE_APPEND](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_APPEND)

Altere a linha

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = cont.openFileOutput(arquivo, 1);
```

para

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = cont.openFileOutput(arquivo, Context.MODE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Eu não conseguia usar o Context.MODE_APPEND, só que não me lembro porque. 
Agora coloquei e passei o armazenamento para interno mas quando o app é encerrado, os dados são perdidos do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Não encontro razão para que isso aconteça. Tenha em conta que cada vez que instala a aplicação os dados são perdidos. Durante o desenvolvimento sempre que faz uma alteração ao programa a aplicação é desinstalada e depois instalada com as alterações.